# Parsing ASN1 data

Tags: java, parsing, bouncycastle, asn.1

I'm supposed to parse **ASN1 encoded byte arrays to a Java object**. My company gave me a documentation with very detailed structures. However in their example of parsing data (no code, just mapping from bits to values):

1. Converting last 7 bytes from HEX to a binary
2. Assigning values based on specific bits in those 7 bytes

There is **no** consideration for **tags and lengths**. The example also just skips the proceeding bytes. I'm not sure how can I parse data like that, using **Bouncy Castle ASN1 library**.

This is the data:

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xECkO.png)

And this is the mapping:

```
22 0....... some field = 0
   .01000.. some field = 8
   ......1. some field = 1
   .......0 some field = 0
```

*Does the ASN1 encoded data have to be in Tag-Length-Value format or can it be using some kind of specific grammar?*

Right now this is my code:

```
ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream = new ASN1InputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                ByteArrayUtil.hexStringToByteArray(
                    "16" + "07" +
                    "22" + "00" + "00" + "19" + "BF" + "12" + "E0")));
        ASN1Primitive deria5String;
        while ((deria5String = asn1InputStream.readObject()) != null) {
            //process
        }
```

Parsing those last 7 bytes gives me object of type DERIA5String.

**Edit 1:** Here is the definition of ASN1 structures I should be getting reading the InputStream:
[image: Data definition]

And this is the example of reading InputStream that I have in documentation:
[image: Example of parsing]

Comment: could you add samle ASN1 grammar definition for the sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the ASN1 encoded data have to be in Tag-Length-Value format or
>   can it be using some kind of specific grammar?

BER and DER encoded data use TLV format.  However, that doesn't mean that some octet string, integer, character string, etc. isn't given some special meaning, not represented in ASN.1, by your application.  If I were to hazard a guess, since "16 07" corresponds to tag [UNIVERSAL 22] and length 7, where that particular tag indicates a character string, I would guess they are parsing some data out of a character string.